# How can I assert a header on an outgoing Mule Request with an Munit Spy

Tags: mule

My mule flow is making an outgoing http request using the `http:request` component. I'm using an `http:request-builder` to add headers to the request.

```
    <http:request doc:name="unnamedImportApi"
        config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration"
        path="${outgoing.api.base_path}/import" method="POST">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="Token token=#[flowVars['api_key']]"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
```

When writing tests, I'm using MUnit mocks and spies to assert the outgoing request contents.  I'm not sure how to get the values of headers in the spy though.  Eg. below I'd like to store the **Authorization** header with the **authHeader** in **spyData**, but am not sure how to acquire the header from the MuleMessage.

```
       Map<String, String> spyData = new HashMap<>();
       spyMessageProcessor("request").ofNamespace("http")
        .withAttributes(attribute("path").withValue(apiPath))
        .before(new SpyProcess() {

            public void spy(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {
                try {
                    spyData.put("payload", event.getMessage().getPayloadAsString());
                    spyData.put("contentType", ""+event.getMessage().getOutboundProperty("Content-type"));
                    spyData.put("method", ""+event.getMessage().getOutboundProperty("http.method"));
                    spyData.put("authHeader", ??????);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("ERROR - Test Spy caused exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    fail("Test Spy threw exception");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there not sure there is a way to do what you want.

You see if you as it was suggested, and set the headers as outbound properties before hand, then you can run assertions in the spy before section and validate that those outbound variables are there.

But if you define them inside the request-build, at the time spy runs those headers haven't been defined yet. That's because the definition of those vars happens INSIDE the connector nor before of after.

Now you may try to run the verify after, but in that case you will be dealing with a message that is the response to the request you sent earlier. So not good.

That said, I reckon you want to ensure you message is going out in the way you defined it. As if you were sniffing. That I think you can not do at least not in an easy way (i.e. not hack way).

I would like to propose something different though. Your production code is:

```
<http:request doc:name="unnamedImportApi"
        config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration"
        path="${outgoing.api.base_path}/import" method="POST">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="Token token=#[flowVars['api_key']]"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
```

Now, you're building your header by setting the value of #[flowVars['api_key']]
You can retrieve that value in your code by doing:

```
spyData.put("authHeader", event.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("api_key"));
```

That should be validation enough, although you can't validate that the static portion of the value  value="Token token= will  be correct. That's something that MUnit should improve.

You should trust that if the request-builder say that by doing

```
<http:header headerName
```

You will end up setting that header, then it should works. 
Is like trusting the API you rely on works properly. So you can focus on testing your own code.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Yeah I thought it might not be possible. I'm used a light server to mock endpoints now, so can sniff headers like that or just set them before. I understand now that it's because the mock replaces the whole component, including the builder inside it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The other way of adding headers to http outbound is by setting outbound properties using mule messsage. 
Set your http header using expression transformer and it will be automatically be received by the http outbound endpoint.

In MUnit you can have access to eventContext as a static variable, using which the mule message can be retrieved and the outbound proeprties can be set or get from it.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I am temporarily setting headers with the `set-property` to get around the issue.  But was hoping I could use the `http:request-builder`.